# Change sizing direction of a label in C#

Tags: c#, .net, label

**Problem**

[http://vvcap.net/db/Bacmovc0t4cZEh-Y_-3Q.png http://vvcap.net/db/Bacmovc0t4cZEh-Y_-3Q.png](http://vvcap.net/db/Bacmovc0t4cZEh-Y_-3Q.png)

**What i hope to achieve**

[http://vvcap.net/db/X6FjDX49q47c7I-gf30J.png http://vvcap.net/db/X6FjDX49q47c7I-gf30J.png](http://vvcap.net/db/X6FjDX49q47c7I-gf30J.png)

Also, when setting to 0 this happens:
http://vvcap.net/db/c3yboadYz9mm_0R7ZRyS.png

While it should do this:
http://vvcap.net/db/UZtjG3QGIbWYQ6ITNn-o.png

How can i do this?

Comment: Show us the code used to create the group box and all the labels inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set label's `TextAlign` property to `TopRight`, `MiddleRight` or `BottomRight`, as you see fit. Since default is `TopLeft`, you'll likely want `TopRight` so that it remains horizontally-aligned with your label on the left.

Also set its width so that it fills the space between the label on the left and the container's right edge.

I suggest you set your other value labels in the same way, so that they will always be right-aligned whatever their displayed text is.

If you expect the whole thing to be resized then you will want to set `Anchor` property accordingly too.

Comment: i've set it to TopRight, still not sizing the right way.

Comment: Have you set the width correctly? You must make the label start right after the "links loaded:" label and end at your container's right edge.

Comment: your solution worked, disable autosize, set width to the adjecent label and then TextAlign TopRight :)